# unsigned short and signed short comparison wierd behavior

Tags: c++, c, 64-bit

When I assign the same value to signed and unsigned `short` and do a comparison it fails but it works with `int`. Unless I cast one or the other to make them same types the comparison is not working.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    signed short b = -10;
    unsigned short  c=-10;
    signed int a = -10;
    unsigned int d=-10;

    printf("%d , %d\n",b,(unsigned short)b);
    printf("%d , %d\n",(signed short)c,c);
    printf("%d , %u\n",a,(unsigned int)a);
    printf("%d , %u\n",(signed int )d,d);
    printf("b==c %d\n", b==c);
    printf("a==d %d\n", a==d);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
./a.out
-10 , 65526
-10 , 65526
-10 , 4294967286
-10 , 4294967286
b==c 0
a==d 1
```

I ran this in sun solaris sparc and hpux itanium with same output. (64 bit exes)

Comment: Why are you comparing apples with oranges?

Comment: This probably is a duplicate, but not of that question.  Although both are related to integer promotion, this one involves widening conversions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because of the integer promotions rules of C.

Here is what's going on: when you try comparing two variables of different types, the compiler checks if each type can be promoted to an `int`. A type can be promoted to `int` when all its possible values fit into an `int`. If a type can be promoted to an `int`, it is promoted to an `int`; otherwise, the compiler checks if it can promote the type to an `unsigned int`. If this promotion is possible, the value is promoted to `unsigned int` before proceeding with the comparison.

In your first example both `signed short` and `unsigned short` can be promoted to an `int`. Once this is done, your get different values, so the comparison returns `false`.

In your second example, however, no promotions are done, because `int` cannot hold all values of `unsigned int` and vice versa. The "raw" comparison is performed, which compares the same representations and returns `true`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That explains it. Perfect!

Comment: The rules are a bit trickier than that.  It would be legal for a platform to define both `int` and `long` to be 35 value bits plus a sign bit, and both `unsigned int` and `unsigned long` to be 35 value bits plus a padding bit.  On such a platform, an operation between `int` and `unsigned long` would convert both operands to `unsigned long` (*even though `int` could represent all values of `unsigned long`!*), but an operation between `long` and `unsigned int` would convert both operands to `long` (even though `unsigned int` was the same size as `unsigned long`).